# return result from model to view (right MVC conception)

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I dont know a good MVC pattern, now learn... So, I want to make: obtain rows from database, if result none (0 rows) print "we have no results", otherwise print results.

In model I have this php code

```
function getAutos () {
    //here connect to database

    $res = $this->db->query("SELECT names FROM auto");
    if ($res->num_rows == 0) {
        return "we have no results";
    }
    else {
        return $res;
    }

}
```

this function  returns object or string, right? now in view I make:

```
<!--some html code -->
<?php
$resultFromGetAutos  = /*result from function getAutos ()*/

if (is_object(resultFromGetAutos)) {
     while ($row = resultFromGetAutos->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo row['names']."<br>";
    }
}
else {
    echo resultFromGetAutos;
}
?>
<!--some html code -->
```

It works, but as I understood, many PHP code  in view, is not right MVC, that is when I check result type in view: `if (is_object(Resultat)) {do something} else { do other something }`  this is not right MVC conception? if not right, how is right way in such situations?

Comment: The view must not know about the model. You have to use a Controller (M V **C**) that calls the function `getAutos()` that just gets the result of the db query, whereafter the controller - and not the model - generates a String to display to the user (if no results are found) or generate the returned table rows in a format the view can directly display.

Comment: So what? @tereško I've seen worse. As long as the intention is clear, it doesn't matter.

Comment: And after your edit it isn't much better @tereško

Answer (score 3):

The model in MVC is not a class or object. Model is [layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_%28object-oriented_design%29), which contains all domain business logic in the application. While it might interact with databases, it should not be directly creating the connection at any point. You might read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719730/dependency-injection-how-to-pass-db-around). It will contain some directions.

The bottom line here is that, what you are calling "model", isn't even close to the original concept.

As for the views, in proper MVC (or MVC-inspired) pattern implementation the views are responsible for all of presentation logic. That would mean that views make the decisions about what will be visible to the user. It is determined by acquiring information from model layer *(by directly requesting it in classical MVC and Model2 MVC, and acquiring it through controller-like structure in MVP and MMVM patterns)*.

In web applications the view creates a response. The form of response would differ based on the for of the request or interface that was used. View can either create response by combining multiple [templates](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) or just sen a HTTP location header.

Comment: I've been getting confused about whether controller hands data directly to view, or just tells view which part of model to access. Your third paragraph was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One of the principles of MVC design is that the Model and the View don't directly access eachother, even don't know about eachother.
Mostly the View is the most stupid. It should *not* understand the data that it is displaying, just how it should display 'data', which could be everything.
You should have a controller that gets noticed by the view if it wants the autos. The controller should then ask the model for the autos, and parse the returned value of the model to a format the view can directly display.
Or, if you should have these autos already on page load, do it via the constructor (example).
It should look *like* this:

```
<View> // you shouldn't include that, that's just that readers notice it is the view.
<?php
    // a bunch of other code
    function AutoView($whatViewShouldDisplay) { // should be the constructor, OOP PHP is not my strongest point
        $content = $whatViewShouldDisplay;
        echo $content;
    }
?>

<Controller>
<?php
    // Bunch of other code
    function AutoController() { // should-be constructor
        $model = new AutoModel();
        $result = $model->getAutos();
        if ($result->num_rows != 0) {
            while ($row = resultFromGetAutos->fetch_assoc()) {
                $viewContent .= row['names']."<br>";
            }
        }
        else {
            $viewContent = "Sorry, no results found.";
        }

        $view = new AutoView($viewContent);
    }
?>

<Model>
<?php
    // Bunch of other code
    function getAutos() {
         return $this->db->query("SELECT names FROM auto");
    }
?>
```

As you see, as long as the Model implements the method `getAutos()` that returns a SQL result set and the view has a one-args constructor you can replace them with everything!

Or, with your code in mind:

```
<!--some html code -->
<?php
$text  = $controller->requestContentForThisPlace(); // Something like getMainContent()? I don't know where this is on your page.

echo $text;
?>
```

And the Controller for your code would implement this method:

```
function requestContentForThisPlace() {
    $result = $model->getAutos();
    if ($result->num_rows != 0) {
        while ($row = resultFromGetAutos->fetch_assoc()) {
            $content .= row['names']."<br>";
        }
    }
    else {
        $content = "Sorry, no results found.";
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: View is not stupid template. And controller does not contain HTML nor should it send data from model layer to view. Please, stop spreading misinformation.

Comment: @tereško and if controller  does not contain HTML, this means that `while` cycle (for print mysql results) must be writed in view right? and assume, from model we obtain string and not object, we already not needed cycle, we need just `echo` right? Question: where must be writed logic: if result is object - write cycle, if result is not object, make just `echo` ?